# Remove rust stains from sink

Tags: cleaning, bathroom

I've tried using cider vinegar and scrubbing and that seems to work better than most conventional cleaners, but it doesn't seem to remove all of the rust.

I've also read that using bleach will "set" the stain making it harder to remove.

So, how should I remove rust stains from a ceramic/porcelain sink?

Answer (score 1):

**Try using:**

- [Salt and Lemon juice](http://www.rd.com/home/cleaning-organizing/8-tips-for-cleaning-a-kitchen-or-bathroom-sink/)

> Rid rust with WD-40. Wipe WD-40 (lighter fluid works, too) on the spot
>   with a cloth and then rinse thoroughly. For rust stains on porcelain
>   enamel sinks, pour salt on half of a lemon and rub it on the stain.

- Baking Soda: This mixed with soap or a acid makes a good cheap scouring powder.

---

**Not a Lifehack**

- [Pumice Scouring Stick](http://homerepair.about.com/od/interiorhomerepair/ss/remv_rust_stain_5.htm#step-heading)

> A pumice scouring stick works well for removing stains from porcelain.
>   I don’t recommend it for fiberglass, but then there are not many
>   fiberglass toilets I know of. With a pumice scouring stick like the
>   Pumie® brand made by United States Pumice Company, you simply wet the
>   bar and rub it back and forth on the stain. You’ll develop a pumice
>   paste which will assist in cleaning and polishing the surface, then
>   simply rinse clean.

**Things I haven't tried:**

- [Naval Jelly](http://www.thriftyfun.com/tf338534.tip.html)

> To get rust stains out of sinks and around drains, use NAVAL Jelly,
>   which can be found in the automotive section.